# Ant design Transform component extracting selected data

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to extract selected/filtered data into the state. I tried everything with onChange and on select change but only I got is the ID of one specific item.

ex. extracted_data = [ '1','2','3'....]
But I need a complete Item with id, name, price, etc...

I am passing data as source data, and after selecting I want to send in the parent component because I need to send it on the server.

Code is below

```
import { Table, Transfer } from "antd";
import difference from "lodash/difference";
import React, { useState } from "react";

// Customize Table Transfer
const TableTransfer = ({ leftColumns, rightColumns, ...restProps }) => (
  <Transfer {...restProps}>
    {({
      direction,
      filteredItems,
      onItemSelectAll,
      onItemSelect,

      selectedKeys: listSelectedKeys,
      disabled: listDisabled,
    }) => {
      const columns = direction === "left" ? leftColumns : rightColumns;

      const rowSelection = {
        getCheckboxProps: (item) => ({
          disabled: listDisabled || item.disabled,
        }),

        onSelectAll(selected, selectedRows) {
          const treeSelectedKeys = selectedRows
            .filter((item) => !item.disabled)
            .map(({ key }) => key);
          const diffKeys = selected
            ? difference(treeSelectedKeys, listSelectedKeys)
            : difference(listSelectedKeys, treeSelectedKeys);
          onItemSelectAll(diffKeys, selected);
        },

        onSelect({ key }, selected) {
          onItemSelect(key, selected);
        },
        selectedRowKeys: listSelectedKeys,
      };

      return (
        <Table
          rowSelection={rowSelection}
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={filteredItems}
          size="small"
          style={{
            pointerEvents: listDisabled ? "none" : undefined,
          }}
          onRow={({ key, disabled: itemDisabled }) => ({
            onClick: () => {
              if (itemDisabled || listDisabled) return;
              onItemSelect(key, !listSelectedKeys.includes(key));
            },
          })}
        />
      );
    }}
  </Transfer>
);

const leftTableColumns = [
  {
    dataIndex: "name",
    title: "Name",
  },
  {
    dataIndex: "price",
    title: "Price (€)",
  },
  {
    dataIndex: "discount",
    title: "Discount (%)",
  },
];
const rightTableColumns = [
  {
    dataIndex: "name",
    title: "Name",
  },
  {
    dataIndex: "price",
    title: "Price",
  },
];

const App = ({ data, func }) => {
  const mockData = data.map((item) => ({
    key: item.id.toString(),
    name: item.name,
    price: item.price,
    discount: item.discount,
  }));
  const originTargetKeys = mockData.map((item) => item.key);

  const [targetKeys, setTargetKeys] = useState(originTargetKeys);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const onSelectChange = (e) => {
    setSelected(e);
  };
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setTargetKeys(e);
    func(selected);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TableTransfer
        dataSource={mockData}
        targetKeys={targetKeys}
        disabled={false}
        showSearch={true}
        onChange={onChange}
        onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
        filterOption={(inputValue, item) =>
          item.name.indexOf(inputValue) !== -1
        }
        leftColumns={leftTableColumns}
        rightColumns={rightTableColumns}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question is as follows: Generate a state to store the transferred objects, then change the onChange function with the following:

```
 const [transferredData, setTransferredData] = useState([]);



const onChange = (nextTargetKeys, direction, moveKeys) => {
    setTargetKeys(nextTargetKeys);

    // Obtener los objetos transferidos
    const transferredItems = mockData.filter((item) =>
      moveKeys.includes(item.key)
    );

    // Actualizar los objetos transferidos
    if (direction === "right") {
      setTransferredData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...transferredItems]);
    } else if (direction === "left") {
      setTransferredData((prevData) =>
        prevData.filter((item) => !moveKeys.includes(item.key))
      );
    }
  };
```